# How to prevent inheriting a rule in a lower width media query

Tags: css

I have a rule in an upper query:

```
@media (max-width: 3000px) { 

    .dropdown-w:hover .dropdown-content-w {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

that is inherited in this media query:

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  
      /*.dropdown-w:hover .dropdown-content-w {
      
      }*/

    .dblock {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Since in a lower width media query I use 'click' to display block the element intead of hovering.
But the hover overrides the click behavior. How to cause that rule not to inherit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `767.98px` is less than `3000px`, every screen-size less than `3000px` gets applied with those media-queries. Same thing is happening here. As `767.98px` is less than `3000px`, media-queries are applied. To not apply for screen size less than `767.98px`, modify your media query

```
@media (min-width: 767.98px) and (max-width: 3000px) {
    .dropdown-w:hover .dropdown-content-w {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Now, windows with screen sizes less than `767.98px` won't inherit the above properties because they are simply not applied to screen sizes below `767.98px`..

Comment: Is it possible to turn off inheriting for a specific rule?

Comment: To make it clear, it is not called **inheriting**, every screen size with less than `3000px` is applied with those properties. If you don't want them below a screen-size, you either override then in a new media-query or specify a min-width in your previous media-query